# CSV file reading and find the value from nth Column using Robot Framework

Tags: python, csv, robotframework, robotframework-ide

Please help me to find the answer for
CSV file reading and find the value from nth Column using Robot Framework
i don't want to use excel-library

I have csv file having 5 columns and 10000 Rows
wanted to find value from 3rd column and 7000 Row using robot framework how will i find the value directly.

I tried below and i am getting value but loop is executing for nth time and that is time consuming and may create performance issues

```
${value1}   Create List             
${FILE_CONTENT} Get File    C:\\abcd1.csv           
Log File Content: ${FILE_CONTENT}               
@{LINES}    Split to Lines  ${FILE_CONTENT}         
Remove From List    ${LINES}    0           
:FOR    ${LINE} IN  @{LINES}        
     Log    ${LINE}         
     @{ROWS}    Split String    ${LINE} separator=, 
     ${VALUE}   Get From List   ${ROWS} 2   
     Log    ${VALUE}            
     ${value2}  Convert To String   ${VALUE}        
     Run Keyword If     ${value2} == 1400000    Exit For Loop       
     Append To List ${value1}   ${value2}           
     Log    ${value1}
```

Comment: Add the code to your question and format it correctly.

Comment: Can you fomat your code and paste it in question itself, its difficult to understand

Comment: @pankajmishra 
did it please check

Comment: Did you check CSV library in RF https://github.com/s4int/robotframework-CSVLibrary/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @pankajmishra
but how will i find the value from the nth cell

Comment: This would be much, much simpler in a python. Do you require a solution that only uses robot keywords? There are also pre-built libraries for dealing with csv files. Is there a reason you aren't using one of them?

Comment: @see my answer,hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly i tried with the inbuilt library as suggested by me to you

github.com/s4int/robotframework-CSVLibrary

i ran across to some errors,which may be because of format of my data.csv , but did not had enough time to debug that.

i created a custom library in python for your solution, you can use it for your work

data.csv

```
Name,Age,region,country,Marks
pankaj,22,delhi,india,45
neeraj,32,noida,india,75
```

python code to parse this data using csv module and return value of nth row and nth column

```
import csv
#Previous function to go to nth row and nth column
def go_to_nth_row_nth_column(File,row_no,col_no):
    inputFile = File
    row_no=int(row_no)
    col_no=int(col_no)
    with open(inputFile) as ip:
        reader = csv.reader(ip)
        for i, row in enumerate(reader):
            if i == row_no:      # here's the row 
                #print row[col_no] # here's the column
                return row[col_no]

#Function to find the string values, in case of duplicate occurrence as well
def search_cell(File,search_string):
    inputFile = File
    search_position=[]  #empty list which will later store row,column occurences
    with open(inputFile) as ip:
        reader = csv.reader(ip)
        for i, row in enumerate(reader):
            for j, column in enumerate(row):
                if search_string in column:      # here's the row 
                    #print((i,j))
                    search_position.append((i,j)) #this will create list of list i.e. list of row,columns in case of multi occurences
                    #return (i,j)   
    return search_position
```

you can use this as library in your robot file , like below

```
*** Settings ***
Library    csv2.py



 *** Test Cases ***
Test
    Check row column
    Search String

*** Keywords ***
Check row column
    ${result} =    go_to_nth_row_nth_column    data.csv    2    1
    log  ${result}

Search String
    ${result1}=    search_cell    data.csv    india
    log  ${result1}
```

Comment: This is awesome,
but i was trying to validate the value let say 
i have value "abc" in one variable 
and in csv same value is present in some column 
and i want to validate by looking it into csv how i will find that  
for ex: when we do ctrl+F and find the value from column that logic i want to apply 
please help

Comment: please go through my example once more, understand it first , and then try to implement some logic as per your requirement

Comment: post your code in question with proper fromatting, this is difficult to understand

Comment: posted please check and help

Comment: Hi Your answer helps as i am new to coding and building logic would request you one more thing please help
I want to search the value in fixed column  i.e. column num  i will provide directly and want to search the string,number how i can get that please help
thanks

Comment: i would suggest you to build some logic and spare some time on it. don't be in hurry. I wont be able to help beyond this point.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @pankaj use library https://github.com/s4int/robotframework-CSVLibrary with following code. This code looks for variable `${value_to_find}`, returns if found otherwise continues the loop and logs the message. You can customize `verify variable` keyword range/loop if want to find it in a single column.

**sample.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Library                     Collections
Library                     CSVLibrary

*** Variables ***
${value_to_find}    Morris

*** Test Cases ***
mytest
    Read file and verify

*** Keywords ***
Read file and verify
  @{list}=  read csv file to list    data.csv
  :FOR    ${x}    IN    @{list}
  \    Log  ${x}
  \    Set test variable    ${x}
  \    verify variable
  \    Run keyword if    ${status}    Log to console    variable was found!
  \    Exit For Loop If    ${status}
  Run keyword if    not ${status}    Log to console    variable was not found!

verify variable
    ${length}=    Get Length    ${x}
  : FOR    ${j}    IN RANGE    0    ${length}
  \    Log    ${x[${j}]}
  \    ${status}=    Evaluate    '${x[${j}]}' == '${value_to_find}'
  \    Log    ${status}
  \    set test variable    ${status}
  \    Exit For Loop If    ${status}
```

**data.csv**

```
id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,ip_address
1,Douglas,Morris,dmorris0@mozilla.org,Male,205.4.212.229
2,Stephanie,Oliver,soliver1@google.com.br,Female,18.101.154.106
3,Russell,Castillo,rcastillo2@shop-pro.jp,Male,255.52.95.46
4,Helen,Reed,hreed3@rambler.ru,Female,167.55.67.109
5,Jesse,Wagner,jwagner4@histats.com,Male,252.37.62.215
6,Ashley,Diaz,adiaz5@wikia.com,Female,79.87.105.139
7,Rachel,Robinson,rrobinson6@blogger.com,Female,132.66.117.101
8,Phillip,Johnston,pjohnston7@disqus.com,Male,70.152.55.21
9,Craig,Burton,cburton8@toplist.cz,Male,73.117.157.82
10,Patrick,Fisher,pfisher9@1und1.de,Male,2.36.191.97
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      ID, Text, Value
      20, Second Item, 200
      30, Third Item, 100
      40, Second Item, 300
      10, First Item, 300
      50, Third Item, 100

      import csv
    def search_cell(string):
    with open("C:\\abcd.csv", "rt") as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for index,row in enumerate(csvreader):
        if string in row[2]:
            print "300 spotted"
            return row

      Robot Code
      ${result2}    search_cell 300
     Log    ${result2}
```

I am getting answer as only

['40', ' Second Item', ' 300']
i want both the column which have 300

Comment: @pankaj mishra,
please check above i am getting but if i want both then what to do 
thanks